# sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, kernel, sklearn-pandas

I have a following problem when i am running the below piece of code. (Fyi.. I have already installed scikit-learn using GIT Shell with the following command pip install -U scikit-learn)

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web
from sklearn.decomposition import KernelPCA
```

I get the following error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8cac97052fa7> in <module>()
  2 import pandas as pd
  3 import pandas.io.data as web
----> 4 from sklearn.decomposition import KernelPCA

C:\Users\Alpha\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>()
 55 else:
 56     from . import __check_build
---> 57     from .base import clone
 58     __check_build  # avoid flakes unused variable error
 59 
11 from .externals import six
12 from .utils.fixes import signature
---> 13 from .utils.deprecation import deprecated
14 from .exceptions import ChangedBehaviorWarning as         _ChangedBehaviorWarning
15 from . import __version__
ImportError: No module named deprecation
```

Comment: Can you show the entire log please ?

Comment: @MMF - Full error message is posted above.